# Can't set Static IP address on iPhone 4S Inital Setup

Tags: iphone

I have an old iPhone 4S that I just bought.

I restored and updated the software so that I had a fresh start on it.

Unfortunately it still has an Apple ID assigned to it so I cannot activate it.

I am trying to follow the instructions in the video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPDgT6vqocI&t=245s which basically needs to change the Wifi settings to specific Static IP settings and specific HTTP Proxy settings however no matter what I try whenever I connect to my router it is reverting back to DHCP settings.

I have tried turning off the DHCP Server on my router temporarily but it keeps getting assigned an an address.

Why won't it keep the specific Wifi settings I am keying into it?

I have tried connecting to the Wifi then entering the settings and the other way around of entering the settings then connecting to the Wifi.

Regards,

Flavio

Comment: You need to contact the person whom you bought the phone from and ask them to deregister the phone from iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

The video you have found is fake. It is probably a scam to earn ad money on Youtube or something like that.

You will need to get the owner of the AppleID to remove the activation lock.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mmmmmm and jksoegaard. Unfortunately I bought this phone in a larger lot at an auction which most likely came from an iPhone repairer so there is no way to locate the owner of this particular handset. I have been trying to find a way around it but have been unsuccessful up to now. The phone is not worth much but it has become a bug bear for me and I have been obsessive to find a solution. I see there is software available but it would cost more for the software than the phone is worth.

Comment: If you could use the iPhone it would be a massive security breach and so I hope that you cannot do anything without contacting the registered owner.